# Action not found after AJAX request

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Before for submitting I want to send the request to an action. But in return I get `404 not found`. The action is obviously there. Also got it in the filters of the controller.
JS:

```
$('#home-contact').on('beforeSubmit', function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: '/site/send-contact',
                        data: new FormData($(this))[0],
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data)                          
                        }
                    })
                    return false
                })
```

Controller filters:

```
'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'signup', 'send-contact'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup', 'send-contact'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

And the action also :

```
public function actionSendContact()
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $model = new Contact();
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){
            return $data['success'] = Yii::t('app', 'Successfully sent message.');
        }
        return $data['error'] = Yii::t('app', 'Something went wrong. Please try again.');
    }
```

The scenario happens in the frontend if that matters somehow. Thank you!

Comment: what url does the request in console shows up is that correct can you add the image of that request? if you write that same url in the browser what do you see?

Comment: and what is the reason behind not using `$.serialize()` and using `new FormData()` instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the `404` you are having as the url in the request is correct and the url that would be generated for the ajax request will be like `http://example.com/site/send-contact` but only if you are using the `'enablePrettyUrl' => true,` for the `urlManager` component, otherwise it should be like `index.php?r=site/index` that could only be the reason behind the `404`, a better way is to get the url from the form `action` attribute.

Apart from above,

You are using the `new FormData()` to send the data with the request like

```
data: new FormData($(this))[0]
```

which isn't correct and won't send any `FormData` with the request as it will return `undefined`, you can check the `console` or by using the `print_r($_POST)` inside the action `sendContact` once you are done with the `404`, it should be

```
data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
```

you need to get the form via `$(this)[0]` and pass to the `new FormData()`.

**But** this is not enough you have to set the `contentType` and `processData` to be `false` to correctly submit the `FormData` or you will get the exception in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

So your code should be like

```
$('#contact-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(){
    let url=$(this).attr('action');
    let form=$(this)[0];
    let data=new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data:data,
        contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)                          
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

**EDIT**

*Note: Above all you should use `data:$(form).serialize()` simply rather than using `new FormData()` until unless you are planning to upload files along with the form using ajax.*

Comment: I found the problem. It was in my url parsing controller ( I got custom one ). But about the jQuery - I am really thankful! Will read more about the `contetnType` and `processData` now. I can mark your answer as correct because it did explain something that can be helpful for someone else. Hope stackoverflow doesn't  mind it.

Comment: you should use `data:$(form).serialize()` simply rather than using `FormData` until unless you are planning to upload files along with the form using ajax. @TomaTomov

Answer (score 0):

URL in JavaScript seems to be not fully specified.

The valid way would be:

```
url: 'index.php?r=site/send-contact',
```

But this works only if your `index.php` is in root folder.

To make it work with any situation (e.g., index.php is not in root), then you have different solutions. I personally like to use this:

- Declare `action` and `id` in your form:

*Example:*

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['site/send-contact'],
    'id' => 'my-form',
]);
```

- Use a link (that is generated by Yii2 itself) in your JS code:

*Example:*

```
$('#home-contact').on('beforeSubmit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: $('#my-form').attr('action'),
        data: new FormData($(this))[0],
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)                          
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This should work in all cases, whenever your files are.

Hope that helps!

Comment: whats with `new FormData($(this))[0]` ? this will give `undefined`

Comment: I used what OP gave in a question. I was looking only at `url:` part here.

Answer (score -1):

did you add     `'enableAjaxValidation' => true` or add action name  in active form?

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['controller/action'],
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true
]);
```

Comment: Why do I need to enable it when I am sending the AJAX request by myself ?

Comment: yeah sorry,  add a complete route in your URL in JS file @TomaTomov

Comment: ajax validation has nothing to do with it